# How to add multiple domains to a single server Dynamically

Tags: networking, dns

I have seen websites like ResellerClub and other white labelled resellers do this .

When you create a white labelled reseller solution you are asked for a domain name upon entering the domain name you will be given a ip address xx.xxx.xxx.xxx

which needs to be added to the CNAME records of the domain name .

how do white labelled resellers manage to point the required data to that particular server ?

Comment: You don't add IP addresses to CNAME records. Also your question is a bit unclear and totally off-topic here, since SO is about programming questions, not about possible hosting solutions.

Comment: I am planning to create a solution like that

Answer (score 0):

You DNS provider to should support to Create CNAME appropriately.

Refer: https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/Whitelabel/domains.html

http://support.tppwholesale.com.au/articles/reseller/how-do-i-make-a-cname-record

You can only have one default whitelabel at a time. By setting a new whitelabel as default, it will replace any other whitelabel you previously set as the default.

Yes, it’s possible to whitelabel multiple domains using the improved whitelabel management process. When multiple whitelabel domains exist on your account, SendGrid will use the from address for each email you send through SendGrid and match it to a domain and link whitelabel. If the from address does not match an existing whitelabel, SendGrid will fall back to the whitelabel you have chosen as the default.

Comment: So How do i find if the traffic is coming from xyz.com so that i can send in response with the appropriate data ?

Comment: This may help you: https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/Whitelabel/faq.html